# My captcha image is not being loaded. There is internal server error 505

Tags: php, captcha

I have a php file for captcha. But image is not there in web page. I cant find out what is the prob. Please help me. Here is my code.

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
// Set the content-type
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
mimetypes.add_type('application/font-ttf', '.ttf', True)
// Create the image
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('bg.jpg');

// Create some colors
$R = rand(0,100);
$G = rand(0,100);
$B = rand(0,100);

$cc = imagecolorallocate($im, $R, $G, $B);


// The text to draw
$text = rand(100,10000);
$_SESSION['text'] = $text;
// Replace path by your own font path
$font = 'arial.ttf';



// Add the text
imagettftext($im, rand(40,45), rand(0,1), rand(10,70), rand(38,50), $cc, $font, $text);
$NumberOfLines=15;
imagecolorallocate($im, 15, 142, 210);

$cc=0;
while($cc < $NumberOfLines){
// set random color:::

//assign random rgb values
$c1 = mt_rand(50,200); //r(ed)
$c2 = mt_rand(50,200); //g(reen)
$c3 = mt_rand(50,200); //b(lue)
//test if we have used up palette
if(imagecolorstotal($im)>=255) {
    //palette used up; pick closest assigned color
    $color = imagecolorclosest($im, $c1, $c2, $c3);
} else {
    //palette NOT used up; assign new color
    $color = imagecolorallocate($im, $c1, $c2, $c3);
}

// done...
$startH =rand(3,200);
$startTOP = rand(0,8);
$stopH=rand(3,200);
$stopTOP =50;

imageline($im, $startH, $startTOP, $stopH, $stopTOP, $color);
$cc++;
}

// Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
imagejpeg($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Name of this script file is img.php And it is set as src of **img**
tag like
img src='img.php'
Here arial.ttf file is in the same folder where this php file resides. Please help me for this. This captcha image is not being loaded.

Comment: what does the error say in your log files, is libjpeg installed?

Comment: There is not any error on web page. Just a small broken image icon. And there is error in console that say :Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: @Miguelo please help me . . .  I need to complete this asap. Thank you for taking interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove the ob_start() command. It does not make much sense (at least to me).
Then uncomment the header(..) line so that you see error messages in the browser.
I had to do the following things to get the code up and running:

- I removed the mimetypes line (is this PHP at all? If yes, a semicolon is missing)
- the script did not find the font - I had to use absolute path and set the permissions right

When you are done with debugging and see fancy chars in your browser window, add the header(..) line again.

Comment: Font file is 'arial.ttf'  and it resides into the same folder where this img.php file is. So I think $font = 'arial.ttf' should work.

But I have set : mimetypes.add_type('application/x-opentype', '.ttf', True);

And I got error in console that say : Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type font/woff: "http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensans/v6/MTP_ySUJH_bn48VBG8sNSnhCUOGz7vYGh680lGh-uXM.woff".

Comment: 1. the mimetypes.add line seems to be Python
2. as for the console - you are talking about Dev Tools in chrome or similar - this is not involved here at all.

Comment: 3. did you remove the first line and uncomment the mime-header line for debugging? You should see error messages now. If not add error_reporting(E_ALL); as a first line

Comment: 4. eventually the browser does not have read access on arial.ttf

Comment: I checked in the way u said, but its still the same. Image is not being generated.

Comment: and: please run the captcha script (i.e. img.php) in your browser and report the error messages you see then

Comment: THIS IS THE ERROR WHEN I RUN IMG.PHP SCRIPT WITH ITS URL IN BROWSER DIRECTLY.
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@geowebhits.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: The code in your question is still the old one including the python line. can you update it?

Comment: I tried as u said, but it didnt make any difference. So I left it as it was. And since then, I havent tried again. So there is nothing to update in the code.

Comment: I have three presumptions: 1. You did not do as I suggested (that's why I wanted to see the code you are currently using, especially that you removed the errors and added the error_reporting all). 2.: you do not have the required php extensions installed (gd...). 3: the font is not readable by the php script. All three presumptions may be true.